# Ways for mapping a directed acyclic graph to a grid / matrix

Tags: algorithm, graph, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have a DAG with many thousands of vertexes and edges.

I'm looking for algorithms that can position the vertexes on grid points in a way that's the most human friendly / aesthetic. My hunch is that the nicest layout would be similar to the layout with minimum sum of edge lengths.

Can you point me to efficient algorithms for such minimum sum of edge lengths layouts, or to other algorithms that could help me tackle this problem?

Here's part of the output from a very naive algorithm:
[image]

Comment: I'm interested in playing around with this problem. Do you have a sample data set you could upload somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this is an open problem ("[graph drawing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_drawing)"). A couple other things you might want to consider optimizing:

- Angle between edges coming from a vertex (maximize)
- Number of edge crossings (minimize)

You might be able to use a genetic algorithm or some other sort of [metaheuristic](http://cs.gmu.edu/~sean/book/metaheuristics/), but I don't know how good the results will be.